# How to know a dimension of matrix or vector in R?

Tags: r, matlab

I want to find the function in R which does the same as the function `size` in Matlab.

In Matlab, if `A = [ 1 2 3 4 5]`, then `size(A) = 1 5`.

If `A =[ 1 2 3;4 5 6]`, then `size(A) = 3 3`.

In R, I found that the function `dim` gives the size of a matrix, but it doesn't apply to vectors.

Please help me solve this problem.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: use `length` for vector,  
`length(A)` will give the size of a vector in R

Comment: I know but A is any object may be it a vector, may be it a matrix, it depend to unkown input

Comment: Here are a couple of useful cheat sheets for R users coming from MATLAB, which show equivalent commands: [R for MATLAB users](http://mathesaurus.sourceforge.net/octave-r.html) // [MATLAB/R Reference](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Hiebeler-matlabR.pdf)

Comment: If `A =[ 1 2 3;4 5 6]` then `size(A) = 2 3`.

Answer (score 12):

Try `dim(A)` it's equal to Matlab size(A) function

Comment: Although the title does refer to matrices, the OP suggests (correctly) that `dim` doesn't work for [single-dimensional] vectors.

Answer (score 7):

Vectors are dimensionless in R, they have length. 
If one wants to consider a vector as a dimensioned object (and later work on that vector), s/he must use `t()` (transpose) (that in essence makes it 1-dimensional array).

```
dim(1:10) # NULL
length(1:10) # 10
dim(t(1:10)) # 1x10
```

Comment: Or NROW/NCOL, which treats a vector as a matrix with ncol=1, so no need to transpose.

Comment: `dim` is very useful

Answer (score 7):

Belated answer, but note that `NROW` and `NCOL` give the dimensions of both vectors and matrices/data.frames. So, for example:

```
> a<-c(1,2,3,4)
> NROW(a);NCOL(a)
[1] 4
[1] 1
```

Answer (score 6):

As you noted `dim` doesn't work on vectors. You can use this function which will take any number of vectors matrices, data.frames or lists and find their `dimension` or `length`:

```
DIM <- function( ... ){
    args <- list(...)
    lapply( args , function(x) { if( is.null( dim(x) ) )
                                    return( length(x) )
                                 dim(x) } )
}

# length 10 vector
a <- 1:10
# 3x3 matrix
b <- matrix(1:9,3,3)
# length 2 list
c <- list( 1:2 , 1:100 )
# 1 row, 2 column data.frame
d <- data.frame( a =1 , b = 2 )


DIM(a,b,c,d)
#[[1]]
#[1] 10

#[[2]]
#[1] 3 3

#[[3]]
#[1] 2

#[[4]]
#[1] 1 2
```

Answer (score 4):

If you don't know if the class of variable `A` is 'matrix' or not, then try:

```
if (class(A) == "matrix" | class(A) == "data.frame") {
  size <- dim(A)
} else {
  size <- length(A)
}

size
```

This should work for your case.

Comment: To generalise to arrays, it might be better to use `if (is.array(A) | is.data.frame(A))`. Or you could use `ifelse(is.null(dim(A)), length(A), dim(A))`, which will return dims if it has them, or else return the number of (top-level) elements.

Comment: @jbaums `ifelse` won't be useful in this situation. `ifelse` returns a value with the same shape (length) as the test. `is.null` is a single logical, so it will return only a single value from `dim` where you expect at least two. That is why my answer is structured the way it is.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following command:

```
c(NROW(w), NCOL(w))
```